# How to update application feature using API call?

Tags: linux, bash, api

We have an api PUT /v1/tbc/subscriber/{id}/{value}/setting using this we have to update the specific application feature(like risk) for almost 5k user. id will always be common but the value will be change every time(example below), how to archive this using bash ? below are the fields for application.

```
{ "downloadNotification":{
   "active": true,
}
"Virusprotection": true,
"risk": true,
"httpsPrtection: true
}
```

Example : - PUT /v1/tbc/subscriber/number/8745627890/setting

Regards,
Ankit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [tag:curl] is what you want.